# Java - How to validate regex expression with multiple parentheses then extract the components from the string?

Tags: java, regex, string, parentheses

I have an input string like:

```
abc(123:456),def(135.666:3434.777),ghi("2015-06-07T09:01:05":"2015-07-08")
```

Basically, it is (naive idea with regex):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(((number)|(quoted datetime)):((number)|(quoted datetime)))(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+(((number)|(quoted datetime)):((number)|(quoted datetime))))+?
```

How can I make a regex pattern in Java to validate that the input string follows this pattern and then I can extract the values `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` and  `((number)|(quoted datetime)):((number)|(quoted datetime))` from them?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Maybe `(\w+)\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?|"[^"]*"):(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|"[^"]*")\)`? See https://regex101.com/r/E4Z1pP/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for helping me with the complex regex pattern.  Please make it as a  comment, then I will mark it as an answer.

Yours just need to have some escapes and it works.
`(\w+)\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\"):(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\")\)`

 https://regex101.com/r/fXqQTG/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(\w+)\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\"):(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\")\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E4Z1pP/3).

In Java, it can be declared as:

```java
String regex = "(\\w+)\\((\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\"):(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\")\\)";
```

*Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\")` - Group 2: one or more digits optionally followed with `.` and one or more digits, or `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\"[^\"]*\")` - Group 3: one or more digits optionally followed with `.` and one or more digits, or `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char
- `\)` - a `)` char